# Tailwind CSS having trouble with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I built a JavaScript game with tailwind CSS. Everything is working pretty fine all the files are well connected to each other, I've made sure that. But still, some of my functions are not working well, in which I am using classList.add or remove function. The style.css file connected as the #start id is working fine but both the pressed and gameOver classes are not getting added to the JavaScript code. I've tried to change the positions of both the classes as well but it didn't work. (The flash animation is not working. Everything is working perfectly on the localhost with the same code)

Style.css code =

```
 @tailwind base; @tailwind components; .pressed {
background: #fff; }, .gameOver {
background-color: rgb(205, 0, 0); }, @tailwind utilities; #start {
margin-left: 6.25rem; }
```

JavaScript Code =

```
function animatePress(currentColor) {
document.querySelector("#" + currentColor).classList.add("pressed");
setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector("#" + currentColor).classList.remove("pressed");
}, 100);}
```

Pls take a look at the full code and also the website.
Full code = [Github Repo](https://github.com/DevABDee/Simon-Game/)

Full Website = [Simon Game](https://devabdee.github.io/Simon-Game/)

Pls help me out, I'm a junior coder and this is my CS50x's final project. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking. You need to ask a specific question for others to help you. Please read [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps edit your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried to inspect your problem, It's not problem with tailwind and javascript.

Actually you're adding *.pressed* class at the end of the classlist for clicked elements. Since the element's *.bg-green-400* and default button type already have some common css rules as *.pressed* class, it's prioritizing the css rules which have already defined before *.pressed*

So, the simple solution would be for this adding **!important** to css property in *.pressed* class which will prioritize the css effect as per requirement.

Solution:

```
.pressed {
   background: #fff !important;
 }
```

Same goes for *.gameOver* class

```
 .gameOver {
   background-color: rgb(205, 0, 0) !important;
 }
```

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: BROOOOO! TYSM. It worked. Thank you again. May Allah Bless you <3